# How to register Callback of Interface using Relfection? Android

Tags: android, reflection

I have an interface:

```
package com.testing.server;

public interface OnViewFoundListener{
     void onViewFound(String msg);
}
```

And the Class that registers Listeners

```
   public class FindViewUtil {
               private static final List<OnViewFoundListener> 
       mOnViewFoundListeners = new ArrayList<>();

      public static void addViewListener(OnViewFoundListener onViewFoundListener) 
      {
        mOnViewFoundListeners.add(onViewFoundListener);
      }

     public static void notifyViewRendered() {
         mOnViewFoundListeners.get(0).onViewFound("Hello World");
     } 

    }
```

I want to be able to register using the addViewListener function and listen for OnViewFoundListener's onViewFound callbacks via Reflection. How can I achieve this goal ?

Comment: You've apparently [used reflection previously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47715653). What problems are you having with this?

Comment: How do I register the callback ? This is different that one was for calling the method, but this one is registering it using reflection.

Comment: It's basically the same thing, though; just calling a method.

Comment: how? I can't just do `public class test implements OnViewFoundListener` since my class doesn't know OnViewFoundListener

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Use a `Proxy`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9583681.

Comment: @MikeM. Proxy seems promising. thanks so much! Although it's a shame i can't create an instance of an interface using reflection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Mike M, using proxy i was able setup the callback.

```
OnViewFoundListener onFoundListner = java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(
          OnViewFoundListener.class.getClassLoader(),
          new java.lang.Class[] { OnViewFoundListener.class },
          new java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler() {
              @Override
              public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
                  //Do stuff here when callback is triggered
                  return null;
              }
          });
```

And Register this instance Callback using Reflection:

```
public void registerUsingReflection(OnViewFoundListener onFoundListner){
              Class[] paramView = new Class[1];
              paramView[0] = Class.class;
              Class findViewUtil = null;
              try {
                  findViewUtil = Class.forName("com.example.FindViewUtil");
                  if (null != findViewUtil) {
                      Constructor constructor = findViewUtil.getDeclaredConstructor();
                      Object clazz = constructor.newInstance();
                      Method setListner = clazz.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("addViewListener", paramView);
                      setListner.invoke(clazz, onFoundListner);
                    return;
                  }
              } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                 e1.printStackTrace();
              } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
                  e1.printStackTrace();
              } catch (NoSuchMethodException e1) {
                  e1.printStackTrace();
              } catch (InvocationTargetException e1) {
                  e1.printStackTrace();
              } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
}
```